# Regex for matching specific words that have whitespace or comma between?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex for javascript which is

```
/^(?!\s*$)(?:car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot|)+$/i
```

It matches some index like this

> bmw mercedes peugeot

but I want it also matches for the cases like

> bmw, mercedes,audi

it should match for all cases for comma ", " "," " ,".

Anybody knows how can I do that ?

edit: The case which is ignoring comma/commas in text is also okay for me
edit: It shouldn't match anything if any word is given which is not in the list.

Comment: Perhaps, [`^(?:car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot)(?:\s*,?\s*(?:car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/3HAM8x/1) will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of this:

- `[^,|^\s]+` where we are excluding any character that is a comma (`,`) or a space (`_`)

You can use `str.match(regex)` to get an array of all the matched elements.

---

```js
const regex = /[^,|^\s]+/gm;

let strSpaces = 'bmw mercedes peugeot';
let strCommas = 'bmw,mercedes,peugeot';
let strSpacesAndCommas = 'bmw mercedes peugeot,bmw mercedes,peugeot';

let regex1 = strSpaces.match(regex);
let regex2 = strCommas.match(regex);
let regex3 = strSpacesAndCommas.match(regex);

regex1.forEach(el => {
  $('#spaces ul').append(`<li>${el}</li>`);
});

regex2.forEach(el => {
  $('#commas ul').append(`<li>${el}</li>`);
});

regex3.forEach(el => {
  $('#spacesAndCommas ul').append(`<li>${el}</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spaces">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="commas">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="spacesAndCommas">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: I am using a platform that allows javascript regular expressions but I cant write codes so I should use sth like "  /^(?!\s*$)(?:car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot|)+$/i   "  so where should I add "[^,|^\s]+" this to my regex

Comment: Here's the [`Regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/ohEgDo/1) link. Have a look there as it has multiple language boilerplates.

Comment: I know that platform but what I want is merge [^,|^\s]+ with my current regex.Is not it possible ? Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: It should only match the words that I give but also it should ignore white space and commas

Comment: `[^,|^\s]+` matches 1 or more any character that is not comma, pipe, caret and space

Answer (score 0):

You can try yhe following regular expression:

```
^((?:car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot)(\s?)+(\,?)(\s?)+)+
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

**Emphasis is mine**

> *"It **shouldn't match anything** if any word is given which is **not in the list**."*

This is an edit from OP explaining an extra criteria...the wording is a little awkward, but going by the first criteria that was accepted (which means I interpreted it correctly), I'm thinking "**shouldn't match anything**" means that nothing should be returned. **not in the list** means that a word in the string being searched has a word that is not in the regex ... well by that logic, it means that anything but:

```
car OR bmw OR mercedes OR audi OR opel OR peugeot OR , OR \s
```

will `return false`, but if that criteria is met, then return only the words not the commas or whitespace. The order and case is unimportant and duplicates are accepted as well. The solution is like Demo 1 with the array method `every()` added as a filter that will `return false` should there be any word that doesn't match. See **Demo 2**.

---

> *"It should only match the words that I give but also it should ignore white space and commas"*

Given a group of words:

```
car bmw mercedes audi opel peugeot
```

from a string with commas and whitespace:

```
`car, Bugatti, Mercedes, Saab, Audi, Opel, Porsche, Peugeot, Volvo, BMW, bmw, bus`
```

The result will be as the first example above in any given order plus duplicates (note in demo result there is a duplicate: `BMW bmw`). The point about the duplicates prove that the `+` quantifier isn't needed in this case.

```
(car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot)
```

Each term separated by OR alternate and everything wrapped as a single capture group. **See Demo 1**.

---

### Demo 1

```js
var rgx = /(car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot)/gi;
var str = `car, Bugatti, Mercedes, Saab, Audi, Opel, Porsche, Peugeot, Volvo, BMW, bmw, bus`;

var res = str.match(rgx);

console.log(res.join(' '));
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
var rgx = /(car|bmw|mercedes|audi|opel|peugeot)/gi;

var str0 = `car, Bugatti, Mercedes, Saab, Audi, Opel, Porsche, Peugeot, Volvo, BMW, bmw, bus`;

var str1 = `Mercedes, Peugeot, bmw, opel, BMW`;

function findOnly(rgx, str) {
  var arr = str.split(',');
  var res = arr.every(function(word) {
    return word.match(rgx);
  });
  if (res === false) {
    return false;
  } else return arr.join(' ');
}

console.log('str0: ' + findOnly(rgx, str0));

console.log('str1: ' + findOnly(rgx, str1));
```